# Apache timing out

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I am developing a new site build using apache on a centos 7.3 box. I have this setup in a load balancer. One one server the sites work perfectly. The second sever the site either times out or gives me err_socket_not_connected. The config, permissions, etc are the same. I can navigate to another site on the same server. I have copied the site files from the first sever to the second, tried disabling .htaccess, changing perms, etc. Nothing seems to be working. There is nothing in any httpd log or the var/log/messages

Comment: I tested this and it appears to be an issue with drupal on the other server. I copied the settings.php and the .htaccess over from the working server and it is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using php-fpm, and have individual pools between each site? The socket timeout error sounds like this might be the case. You should enable error logging for each site and check the error logs for php errors. You may need to increase some settings like max_execution_time, or memory_limit, etc. It could also be that the fcgi socket timeout value in your vhost conf differs between the two sites. For drupal or any CMS, I would set a minimum of 1800.